# How to compare two different enums by meaning without resorting to .ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Spoiler: legacy code, C#, .NET 4.52

I am looking for alternative solutions to compare two different enum values, that are declared in different projects in a different order but equal in meaning and name.
Like `EnumDecl1.FirstName` has the same meaning as `EnumDecl2.FirstName` but their underlying values are different (they have been declared by different working groups in different projects but communicate with each other through web services).

Throughout the existing code base they use basically this:

```
if(var1.ToString().Equals(EnumDecl2.FirstName.ToString() 
   || var1.ToString().Equals(EnumDecl2.SecondName.ToString())
```

In some cases with a call to `ToUpper`/`ToLower` to make things more interesting. Now make this comparison a few dozen times in one method and you have an insect crawling over a roadblock.

The Equals() on the enum cant be overridden or extended, so what other suggestions can you come up with to improve comparison (ignore the `var1.ToString()` as this can be put into a variable).

This is 15+ years old code, spread over a huge codebase. I am looking for ways to gradually improve it.

Comment: Enums are integers. Why all this mess with strings? Just cast them to int and check the values.

Comment: Because they are in different order, as mentioned in the question. So EnumDecl1.FirstName has a different int value than EnumDecl2.FirstName.

Comment: _I am looking for ways to gradually improve it._ Extract the common code to a published and versioned nuget package, where each solution/project uses the published package.  When communicating through web services, ensure the enums are serialized using their name (not ordinal value) so that if one working group inserts a new enum in the middle the other side will still function as expected, even when still using an older version of the package.  And if there is a code review process, set up a policy on the shared repo that houses the common code to require a reviewer from both working groups.

Comment: @AndrewS How does that solve the question of avoiding ToString() ?

Comment: @Hefaistos68 - since both sides would use the same package, the condition could be simplified to `if(var1 == SharedEnum.FirstName || var1 == SharedEnum.SecondName)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the ideas of the extension method and the `Dictionary`

```cs
public static class FirstTypeEnumExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<FirstTypeEnum, SecondTypeEnum> _firstTypeToSecondTypeMap = new Dictionary<FirstTypeEnum, SecondTypeEnum>
    {
        {FirstTypeEnum.First, SecondTypeEnum.First},
        {FirstTypeEnum.Second, SecondTypeEnum.Second},
        {FirstTypeEnum.Third, SecondTypeEnum.Third}
    };

    public static bool IsEquivalentTo(this FirstTypeEnum first, SecondTypeEnum second)
    {
        var success = _firstTypeToSecondTypeMap.TryGet(first, out var mappedSecond);
        if (!success)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(FirstTypeEnum)} {first} does not have a mapping defined to {nameof(SecondTypeEnum)}", nameof(first));

        return mappedSecond == second;
    }
}
```

when using the extension it would look like this

```cs
if (firstType.IsEquivalentTo(secondType))
{
    ...
}
```

Updated solution with auto populated maps and bidirectional extensions

```cs
   Dictionary<int, int> map1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
   Dictionary<int, int> map2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

   // build the maps
   foreach(var e1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumDecl1)))
      map1.Add((int)e1, ((int)Enum.Parse<EnumDecl2>(e1.ToString())));

   foreach(var e2 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumDecl2)))
      map2.Add((int)e2, ((int)Enum.Parse<EnumDecl1>(e2.ToString())));


   // extension methods to compare them both ways
    public static bool Is(this EnumDecl1 first, EnumDecl2 second)
    {
        var success = map2.TryGetValue((int)second, out var mappedSecond);

        return success && (mappedSecond == (int)first);
    }

    public static bool Is(this EnumDecl2 first, EnumDecl1 second)
    {
        var success = map1.TryGetValue((int)second, out var mappedSecond);

        return success && (mappedSecond == (int)first);
    }
```

Comment: Based on this idea I worked out a way to compare using int maps, dynamically built on startup so it does not require code changes when any enum is altered. And its about 12 times faster than the string compare. Expected more but compared with reduced memory usage its already something.

Comment: To be clear the updated solution was added by @Hefaistos68 as an edit, I cleaned the edit, but that made the edit show up as my own edit.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is that when a value of a specific type is needed, the conversion is made and the necessary operations are carried out.

e.g.
I have `EnumTeamA` value but i need to call a function with `EnumTeamB` parameter. The conversion is necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public enum EnumTeamA
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3,
    Fourth = 4,
    Fifth = 5
}

public enum EnumTeamB
{
    A = 100,
    B = 200,
    C = 300,
    D = 400,
    E = 500
}


public static class EnumExtensions
{
    private static ReadOnlyDictionary<EnumTeamA, EnumTeamB> TeamADictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<EnumTeamA, EnumTeamB>(new Dictionary<EnumTeamA, EnumTeamB>
        {
            { EnumTeamA.First, EnumTeamB.A},
            { EnumTeamA.Second, EnumTeamB.B},
            { EnumTeamA.Third, EnumTeamB.C},
            { EnumTeamA.Fourth, EnumTeamB.D},
            { EnumTeamA.Fifth, EnumTeamB.E}
        });
    private static ReadOnlyDictionary<EnumTeamB, EnumTeamA> TeamBDictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<EnumTeamB, EnumTeamA>(new Dictionary<EnumTeamB, EnumTeamA>
        {
            { EnumTeamB.A, EnumTeamA.First},
            { EnumTeamB.B, EnumTeamA.Second},
            { EnumTeamB.C, EnumTeamA.Third},
            { EnumTeamB.D, EnumTeamA.Fourth},
            { EnumTeamB.E, EnumTeamA.Fifth}
        });

    public static EnumTeamB Convert(this EnumTeamA key)
    {
        EnumTeamB value;
        bool ok = TeamADictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return ok ? value : throw new NotImplementedException("Invalid enum value: " + key.GetType().FullName);
    }

    public static EnumTeamA Convert(this EnumTeamB key)
    {
        EnumTeamA value;
        bool ok = TeamBDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return ok ? value : throw new NotImplementedException("Invalid enum value: " + key.GetType().FullName);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void FunctionThatNeedsEnumTeamA(EnumTeamA value)
    {
        // Your custom code 
    }

    public static void FunctionThatNeedsEnumTeamB(EnumTeamB value)
    {
        // Your custom code
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Context 1 - You have EnumTeamA value but need to call a function with EnumTeamB value.
        EnumTeamA enumTeamAValue = EnumTeamA.Fourth;
        FunctionThatNeedsEnumTeamB(enumTeamAValue.Convert());

        // Context 2 - You have EnumTeamB value but need to call a function with EnumTeamA value.
        EnumTeamB enumTeamBValue = EnumTeamB.D;
        FunctionThatNeedsEnumTeamA(enumTeamBValue.Convert());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one, similar to what we came up with up there. I also added a dynamic map that doesnt need updating when the enums change., but it depends on same name of enum members.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a dictionary. For example, if we have the following two enums:

```
enum Enum1 { Value1, Value2, Value3 }
enum Enum2 { Value3, Value1, Value2 }
```

...we can write something like this:

```
// You probably want to declare this globally and instantiate only once.
var enumDictionary = new Dictionary<Enum1, Enum2>
{
    { Enum1.Value1, Enum2.Value1 },
    { Enum1.Value2, Enum2.Value2 },
    { Enum1.Value3, Enum2.Value3 }
};

// Create a bogus value of Enum1.
Enum1 e1 = GetEnum1();
// Get the corresponding Enum2 value.
Enum2 e2 = enumDictionary[e1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first make an method:

```
       public bool IsEqual(EnumDecl1 enumDec1, EnumDecl2 enumDec2)
        {
            return enumDec1.ToString() == enumDec2.ToString() ? true : false;
        }
```

And calling the method giving the 2 values you want to check.

```
if(IsEqual(EnumDecl1.FirstName,EnumDecl2.SecondeName))
{
    do something...
}
```

Comment: A ternary expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`. Really?

Comment: WITHOUT RESORTING TO ToString() was the OPs request. Read the post please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement.

```
enum Enum1 { Value1, Value2, Value3 }
enum Enum2 { Value3, Value2, Value1 }

switch (enum1)
{
    case Enum1.Value1:
        return enum2 == Enum2.Value1;
    case Enum1.Value2:
        return enum2 == Enum2.Value2;
    case Enum1.Value3:
        return enum2 == Enum2.Value3;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

My only note is this could cause issues down the road if you ever plan on adding values to either enum as you would also need to remember to update this switch....

Answer (score 0):

Since these various projects communicate via web services, I would tackle a problem like this in the following manner:

1. Decide on a canonical definition for the enum that you would eventually like to move the entire code base to. You might not actually ever get there, but it's good to have a target.
2. For an individual project, make sure that whenever you get data from a web service, you immediately map the relevant values to your canonical enum. In that project you would never convert those enums to strings (unless you needed to display them for some reason). You could compare the enums directly. If you need to send data to another web service, map the enums to the value that web service expects.
3. When you need to update another project, make sure that the enum definitions match your canonical enums and do the same thing with inputs and outputs. If you ever get to the point where you've done this with the whole code base you can move the enum definition into a shared project to make it easier to maintain compatibility and you could get rid of all the mapping code.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. When you have the possibility to interfere in dozens of projects spread over as many teams. Those values are in databases and innumerous structures already. So this is a no go.